# Two different mysql tables into a third table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables:

table 1: product

```
    productId  productName
       1         One    
       2         Two
```

table 2: branch

```
    branchId  branchName
       1       Branch One
       2       Branch Two
       3       Branch Three
```

these two tables need to be merged into a third table

table 3: productopening

```
    openId  productId branchId
```

The id is an auto increment id. the first two tables have data that are not related. I mean, row for id=1 in table 1 has nothing to do with the row for id=1 in table two. So, I basically want to write a mysql script which would insert values into table 3 to look like this in the end:

table 3: productopening

```
    openId  productId  branchId
       1        1         1
       2        1         2
       3        1         3
       4        2         1
       5        2         2
       6        2         3
```

the ids in the old tables and the new table don't have to match. Just the data from the tables need to be in the new table. I am very new to mysql and if anyone can help me with this, it would be great!

That's It.

Comment: you can use cross join to generate this kind of data !

Comment: Thanks you for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cross join  and insert select

```
insert into productopening
select product.id, branch.id 
from product
crossjoin branch
```

if you need an ordered  result (order in insert have no sense) you must explict an order by clause in select

```
select id, productId  , branchId
from productopening
order by productId  , branchId
```

or if you need that the creation of the productopening id is ordered then  you can use and ordered select

```
insert into productopening
select product.id, branch.id 
from product
crossjoin branch
order by product.id, branch.id
```

Comment: I have already trying with cross join but it not works perfect.

Comment: I need result look like last table 3:

Comment: then update your question and add  the result you obtain with my answer ...because  .. for waht i know should retunrn the result you have in question ..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will work:

`INSERT INTO productopening(SELECT null, product.productId, branch.branchId FROM 
product CROSS JOIN branch ORDER BY product.productId);`